# How do I use encode (Python 3) to fix non-ascii code for CSV import in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The CSV file I'm trying to read in pandas has a non-ascii character but I'm not having any luck with the encode function.  I'm using python 3.

The error I originally got was...

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position
>   252: invalid start byte

So I used `file_name.encode('ascii')` but now getting...

> OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got  type

My code...

```
import pandas as pd

location = "C:\\Downloads\\"
file = "file.csv"

file_name = location + file

master = pd.read_csv(file_name.encode('ascii'))
df = master
df
```

I know there is a character in there that needs to be encoded so just trying to write something that allows pandas to read the CSV.

Thanks so much!

Comment: can you include a sample of the contents of file.csv? We can't reproduce your error without that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't want to use ASCII encoding on the file name.  You want to read the data in the file, with the encoding of that file, and then create a pandas dataframe from that existing CSV data.

As per [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), read_csv can work with a file object just as easily as it can work with a path to that file.

At it's simplest, you want something like:

```
file_obj = open(file_name, encoding="utf-8")
master = pd.read_csv(file_obj)
```

Of course, if the encoding *isn't* utf-8, you'll want to put the appropriate encoding in the `open` command.  If you don't know the encoding, just try the typical encodings one at a time until one works.  The most popular are 'utf-8', 'ascii', and 'latin-1'.

Comment: The character mentioned in the error message (`x0A`) is a non-breaking space in latin-_n_ encodings, so 'latin-1' would be my first try.