# How to convert 2 DataFrame columns to ascii?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, ascii

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns of strings, imported from a tsv file. Both columns need to be converted to ascii. (This is because I want to pass the text through a CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer pipeline in scikit-learn).

I have gone through dozens of posts both on stackoverflow as well as outside, but cannot figure this one out. My code is below, including some of the things I have tried.

Any suggestions to make this work?

```
# tried including adding encoding="utf-8", does not work
df = pd.read_csv(questions, usecols = [3, 4, 5], nrows = 10, header=0, sep="\t") 

y = df["is_duplicate"].values
X = df.drop("is_duplicate", axis=1).values

for col in X:
    X = X.encode('utf-8') # does not work

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3,
random_state = 21, stratify = y)

def flat_list(my_list):
    return [str(item) for sublist in my_list for item in sublist]

def transform_data(trans_obj_list,dataset_splits):
    X_train = dataset_splits[0].astype(str)

X_train = flat_list(X_train)

for trfs in trans_obj_list:
    transformed_vector = trfs().fit(X_train)
    for x in range(0,len(dataset_splits)):
        dataset_splits[x] =flat_list(dataset_splits[x].astype(str))

return dataset_splits

new_X_train, new_X_test = transform_data([CountVectorizer,TfidfTransformer],
[X_train, X_test])
```

Comment: Check my answer otherwise, could you please share a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `X.str.encode(..)` instead of `X.encode(..)` like this:

```
for col in X:
    X = X.str.encode('utf-8') # does not work
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question in this question: [How do I use encode (Python 3) to fix non-ascii code for CSV import in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44809113/how-do-i-use-encode-python-3-to-fix-non-ascii-code-for-csv-import-in-pandas)

```
file_obj = open(file_name, encoding="utf-8")
master = pd.read_csv(file_obj)
```

I just used "ascii" instead of "utf-8" for my case.